# Android app FCM not work after upload to PlayMarket

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have really strange problem... When I test my app by run it from Android Studio via adb on my device FCM work fine: I receive message.
After upload app to PlayMarket and install it on my device I don't receive any messages, but FMC answer is:{"multicast_id":1695544074387685194,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1601671971820497%9fd56643f9fd7ecd"}]}

Anyone can help me, what it can be a problem?... Thanks!

I add sha1 and sha256 from this:
[image]

but I still not receive the message

Comment: Add your app release build sha1 key into firebase as that u hv done for your debug build version.

Comment: thanks for answer, and where I can get this sha1 key?...